# Large position replace using PHP string replace

Tags: javascript, php, html, str-replace, file-get-contents

It easy to replace a position of code from external website string but when it come to large than how can we replace it?

Code i want to replace from example.com :

```
<script data-cfasync="false" src="/cdn-cgi/scripts/5c5dd728/cloudflare-static/email-decode.min.js"></script><script nonce="d5951f1b7cde348759b0310ef405830a">
  window.RETROVISION = {
    "homepage": {
      "__render-farm": {"navi":{"variation":"logged_out","darwin":{"mono.corePages_indexController_transactionAccounts":false,"mono.navigation_web_moneyCenterTab":true,"mono.navigation_web_hideMyRecsBadge":false,"mono.taxhub_enabled":true,"mono.enableCardsInWallet":false,"mono.should_show_ciw_in_nav_cc_dropdown":false,"mono.tax_navbar_inseason":false,"mono.navigation_web_nativeUpsell":"control","mono.tax_hub_holdout":true,"autos.purchase_offers_navi_url_enabled":true,"js.cardsInWallet_holdout":false,"js.navi_voter_roadmap_isEnabled":false,"js.navi_voter_roadmap_text":"Voter\x20Roadmap","js.reliefCenter_navbar_badge_text":"control","js.useNewLoginNavi":false,"savings.navbar_enabled":true,"mortgage.l1_link_in_authed_navi":true,"mortgage.l1_link_in_unauthed_navi":true,"savings.checking_be_eligibility_flag_v2":true,"savings.billpay_eligible":true,"mortgage.mweb_navi_new_dashboard_link":"new","coreProduct.dweb_stickyTopEnabled":false,"portals.reliefCenter_isEnabled":true,"portals.tax_nav_redirect_enabled":false,"portals.tax_surface_eligibility_unauth":true,"mono.tax_navbar_badge_text":"control","mono.tax_unauth_navbar_badge_text":"","navigation":{"web":{"isMobile":false}}},"version":"10.32.0","moduleName":"navi","bundleName":"navi-inline-retrovision.bundle.js","nonce":{"script":"d5951f1b7cde348759b0310ef405830a"}},"darwin":{"mono":{"homepage_version":"b","homepage_enable_criticalCss":true,"homepage_section_1":"kc_cc_pl_v1","homepage_section_2":"v1","homepage_section_3":"money","homepage_section_4":"v1","homepage_section_5":"v1","homepage_section_6":"v1","homepage_section_7":"v1","homepage_section_8":"v1","homepage_section_9":"v1"}},"navigation-web":{"darwin":{"coreProduct.scooter_mweb_notificationCenterEnabled":true,"coreProduct.scooter_dweb_navPlacement":"top","coreProduct.scooter_dweb_navCopy":"scooter","mono.tax_navbar_badge_text":"control","coreProduct.scooter_mweb_newNavIconsEnabled":false,"coreProduct.scooter_dweb_myRecsEnabled":false,"coreProduct.scooter_dweb_myRecsBadgeEnabled":false,"coreProduct.scooter_dweb_autoHomeEnabled":false},"platformInfo":{"platform":"Web","osType":null},"nonce":"d5951f1b7cde348759b0310ef405830a"},"ckRawTracker":{"enabled":true,"url":"https:\x2F\x2Fcreditkarmacdn-a.akamaihd.net\x2Fres\x2Fcontent\x2Fbundles\x2Fcfwk_raw-tracker-web\x2F2.8.1\x2Findex.js","hash":"sha384-LIWRu\x2Fm\x2FCPYkQvDB\x2B6CsmuSqzmdqkZg5VJavhsyvLG1Ly2iXMcOcy8TnMRV65K0O"},"footer":{"darwin":{"mono.geolocation":"hide"},"version":"4.9.8","moduleName":"footer","bundleName":"footer-retrovision.bundle.js","nonce":"d5951f1b7cde348759b0310ef405830a","location":{"country":"US","continent":"NA","subdivision":"OH","zipCode":"43215"},"domain":"US"},"zipkin":{"enabled":false},"request":{"tokens":{"accessToken":false,"refreshToken":false},"cookieId":"6AA3886FD63D41C9B5E1933E22065C85","params":{},"path":"\x2F","fullPath":"https:\x2F\x2Fwww.creditkarma.gq\x2F","traceId":"3234806a-8570-4eec-bace-c58e2b462102"},"isScooter":false,"geoipData":{"country":"US","continent":"NA","subdivision":"OH","zipCode":"43215"},"nonce":"d5951f1b7cde348759b0310ef405830a","platformInfo":{"platform":"Web","osType":null}}
    }
  };
</script>
```

I want to replace whole code

My Code :

```
$cloudflare = '<script data-cfasync="false" src="/cdn-cgi/scripts/5c5dd728/cloudflare-static/email-decode.min.js"></script><script nonce="d5951f1b7cde348759b0310ef405830a">
  window.RETROVISION = {
    "homepage": {
      "__render-farm": {"navi":{"variation":"logged_out","darwin":{"mono.corePages_indexController_transactionAccounts":false,"mono.navigation_web_moneyCenterTab":true,"mono.navigation_web_hideMyRecsBadge":false,"mono.taxhub_enabled":true,"mono.enableCardsInWallet":false,"mono.should_show_ciw_in_nav_cc_dropdown":false,"mono.tax_navbar_inseason":false,"mono.navigation_web_nativeUpsell":"control","mono.tax_hub_holdout":true,"autos.purchase_offers_navi_url_enabled":true,"js.cardsInWallet_holdout":false,"js.navi_voter_roadmap_isEnabled":false,"js.navi_voter_roadmap_text":"Voter\x20Roadmap","js.reliefCenter_navbar_badge_text":"control","js.useNewLoginNavi":false,"savings.navbar_enabled":true,"mortgage.l1_link_in_authed_navi":true,"mortgage.l1_link_in_unauthed_navi":true,"savings.checking_be_eligibility_flag_v2":true,"savings.billpay_eligible":true,"mortgage.mweb_navi_new_dashboard_link":"new","coreProduct.dweb_stickyTopEnabled":false,"portals.reliefCenter_isEnabled":true,"portals.tax_nav_redirect_enabled":false,"portals.tax_surface_eligibility_unauth":true,"mono.tax_navbar_badge_text":"control","mono.tax_unauth_navbar_badge_text":"","navigation":{"web":{"isMobile":false}}},"version":"10.32.0","moduleName":"navi","bundleName":"navi-inline-retrovision.bundle.js","nonce":{"script":"d5951f1b7cde348759b0310ef405830a"}},"darwin":{"mono":{"homepage_version":"b","homepage_enable_criticalCss":true,"homepage_section_1":"kc_cc_pl_v1","homepage_section_2":"v1","homepage_section_3":"money","homepage_section_4":"v1","homepage_section_5":"v1","homepage_section_6":"v1","homepage_section_7":"v1","homepage_section_8":"v1","homepage_section_9":"v1"}},"navigation-web":{"darwin":{"coreProduct.scooter_mweb_notificationCenterEnabled":true,"coreProduct.scooter_dweb_navPlacement":"top","coreProduct.scooter_dweb_navCopy":"scooter","mono.tax_navbar_badge_text":"control","coreProduct.scooter_mweb_newNavIconsEnabled":false,"coreProduct.scooter_dweb_myRecsEnabled":false,"coreProduct.scooter_dweb_myRecsBadgeEnabled":false,"coreProduct.scooter_dweb_autoHomeEnabled":false},"platformInfo":{"platform":"Web","osType":null},"nonce":"d5951f1b7cde348759b0310ef405830a"},"ckRawTracker":{"enabled":true,"url":"https:\x2F\x2Fcreditkarmacdn-a.akamaihd.net\x2Fres\x2Fcontent\x2Fbundles\x2Fcfwk_raw-tracker-web\x2F2.8.1\x2Findex.js","hash":"sha384-LIWRu\x2Fm\x2FCPYkQvDB\x2B6CsmuSqzmdqkZg5VJavhsyvLG1Ly2iXMcOcy8TnMRV65K0O"},"footer":{"darwin":{"mono.geolocation":"hide"},"version":"4.9.8","moduleName":"footer","bundleName":"footer-retrovision.bundle.js","nonce":"d5951f1b7cde348759b0310ef405830a","location":{"country":"US","continent":"NA","subdivision":"OH","zipCode":"43215"},"domain":"US"},"zipkin":{"enabled":false},"request":{"tokens":{"accessToken":false,"refreshToken":false},"cookieId":"6AA3886FD63D41C9B5E1933E22065C85","params":{},"path":"\x2F","fullPath":"https:\x2F\x2Fwww.creditkarma.gq\x2F","traceId":"3234806a-8570-4eec-bace-c58e2b462102"},"isScooter":false,"geoipData":{"country":"US","continent":"NA","subdivision":"OH","zipCode":"43215"},"nonce":"d5951f1b7cde348759b0310ef405830a","platformInfo":{"platform":"Web","osType":null}}
    }
  };
</script>'
$homepage = file_get_contents("https://www.example.com");
$homepage = str_replace($cloudflare, "hello", $homepage);
echo $homepage;
```

Is it possible to replace like this?

```
$homepage = str_replace('<script data-cfasync=\***/</script>', "hello", $homepage);
```

Comment: seems like you're trying to scrap a page then strip out the bits you don't want, if so, do the opposite, scrap the page for what you do want ignoring everything else

Comment: with regex https://3v4l.org/Y8lBH

Comment: @LawrenceCherone scrapping the page do not give real time data. means if something change in `example.com` it will get automatically changed with `file_get_contents`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone can you tell me why you added `(.*?)` in between link instead of using full link `/cdn-cgi/scripts/5c5dd728/cloudflare-static/email-decode.min.js`

Comment: 5c5dd728 would be a build hash/version so its most likely going to change

Comment: @LawrenceCherone so i have to use `(.*?)` for dynamic content and `([^<]*)` for middle content ? and what is the meaning of `#` in starting & ending

Comment: `(.*?)` will match all but newlines so cant use it in place of `([^<]*)` which matches all but anything starting with `<`, which is the start of the last `</script>`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone got it. Thank you so much for help!!

Comment: np, happy scrapping ;p

Comment: @LawrenceCherone i did exactly what you said. i used `(.*?)` for random value but it still not working :(. check my Code here : https://3v4l.org/QIEi9

Comment: yeah your regex expression is not valid, it needs enclosing in a valid wrapper, i.e `/` or `#` etc (not sure what its called), then you need to remove the `?` as your capture ends, also you need to escape `?` as it means somthing. i.e the https://3v4l.org/pifGu

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I understand we need to use `#` for in starting and ending and `(.*)` random values but the question last time you used `?` for random values like `(.*?)`

Comment: it means greedy and non greedy, the string you was matching was not the same as the original question, so it has a different solution because you have a capture at the end of what your matching. you can test regex at regex101, also more info can be found here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression about regex

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thanks again for helping me to understand. I will learn more about regex101. Take care mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @LawrenceCherone for solution.

Full Code :

```
<?php
$str = 'foo 
<script src="something/else1.js"></script>

<script data-cfasync="false" src="/cdn-cgi/scripts/5c5dd728/cloudflare-static/email-decode.min.js"></script><script nonce="d5951f1b7cde348759b0310ef405830a">
  window.RETROVISION = {
    "homepage": {
      "__render-farm": {"navi":{"variation":"logged_out","darwin":{"mono.corePages_indexController_transactionAccounts":false,"mono.navigation_web_moneyCenterTab":true,"mono.navigation_web_hideMyRecsBadge":false,"mono.taxhub_enabled":true,"mono.enableCardsInWallet":false,"mono.should_show_ciw_in_nav_cc_dropdown":false,"mono.tax_navbar_inseason":false,"mono.navigation_web_nativeUpsell":"control","mono.tax_hub_holdout":true,"autos.purchase_offers_navi_url_enabled":true,"js.cardsInWallet_holdout":false,"js.navi_voter_roadmap_isEnabled":false,"js.navi_voter_roadmap_text":"Voter\x20Roadmap","js.reliefCenter_navbar_badge_text":"control","js.useNewLoginNavi":false,"savings.navbar_enabled":true,"mortgage.l1_link_in_authed_navi":true,"mortgage.l1_link_in_unauthed_navi":true,"savings.checking_be_eligibility_flag_v2":true,"savings.billpay_eligible":true,"mortgage.mweb_navi_new_dashboard_link":"new","coreProduct.dweb_stickyTopEnabled":false,"portals.reliefCenter_isEnabled":true,"portals.tax_nav_redirect_enabled":false,"portals.tax_surface_eligibility_unauth":true,"mono.tax_navbar_badge_text":"control","mono.tax_unauth_navbar_badge_text":"","navigation":{"web":{"isMobile":false}}},"version":"10.32.0","moduleName":"navi","bundleName":"navi-inline-retrovision.bundle.js","nonce":{"script":"d5951f1b7cde348759b0310ef405830a"}},"darwin":{"mono":{"homepage_version":"b","homepage_enable_criticalCss":true,"homepage_section_1":"kc_cc_pl_v1","homepage_section_2":"v1","homepage_section_3":"money","homepage_section_4":"v1","homepage_section_5":"v1","homepage_section_6":"v1","homepage_section_7":"v1","homepage_section_8":"v1","homepage_section_9":"v1"}},"navigation-web":{"darwin":{"coreProduct.scooter_mweb_notificationCenterEnabled":true,"coreProduct.scooter_dweb_navPlacement":"top","coreProduct.scooter_dweb_navCopy":"scooter","mono.tax_navbar_badge_text":"control","coreProduct.scooter_mweb_newNavIconsEnabled":false,"coreProduct.scooter_dweb_myRecsEnabled":false,"coreProduct.scooter_dweb_myRecsBadgeEnabled":false,"coreProduct.scooter_dweb_autoHomeEnabled":false},"platformInfo":{"platform":"Web","osType":null},"nonce":"d5951f1b7cde348759b0310ef405830a"},"ckRawTracker":{"enabled":true,"url":"https:\x2F\x2Fcreditkarmacdn-a.akamaihd.net\x2Fres\x2Fcontent\x2Fbundles\x2Fcfwk_raw-tracker-web\x2F2.8.1\x2Findex.js","hash":"sha384-LIWRu\x2Fm\x2FCPYkQvDB\x2B6CsmuSqzmdqkZg5VJavhsyvLG1Ly2iXMcOcy8TnMRV65K0O"},"footer":{"darwin":{"mono.geolocation":"hide"},"version":"4.9.8","moduleName":"footer","bundleName":"footer-retrovision.bundle.js","nonce":"d5951f1b7cde348759b0310ef405830a","location":{"country":"US","continent":"NA","subdivision":"OH","zipCode":"43215"},"domain":"US"},"zipkin":{"enabled":false},"request":{"tokens":{"accessToken":false,"refreshToken":false},"cookieId":"6AA3886FD63D41C9B5E1933E22065C85","params":{},"path":"\x2F","fullPath":"https:\x2F\x2Fwww.creditkarma.gq\x2F","traceId":"3234806a-8570-4eec-bace-c58e2b462102"},"isScooter":false,"geoipData":{"country":"US","continent":"NA","subdivision":"OH","zipCode":"43215"},"nonce":"d5951f1b7cde348759b0310ef405830a","platformInfo":{"platform":"Web","osType":null}}
    }
  };
</script> 
<script src="something/else2.js"></script>
bar';

echo preg_replace('#<script data-cfasync="false" src="/cdn-cgi/scripts/(.*?)/cloudflare-static/email-decode.min.js"></script><([^<]*)</script>#', 'hello', $str);
```

Syntax Code :

```
echo preg_replace('#<script data-cfasync="false" src="/cdn-cgi/scripts/(.*?)/cloudflare-static/email-decode.min.js"></script><([^<]*)</script>#', 'hello', $str);
```

Explanation :

> `#` or `/` - Starting and ending
>
> `(.*)` - Random Value
>
> `([^<]*)` or `([^anything]*)` - search with
>
> `(.*?)` - Unknown